# Php code problems (function?)

Tags: php

anyone can help me find problem in this code?
Why the page still display 'Good'?

```
<?php
$badinput=false;

function check($arg1,$arg2)
{
    if(($arg1<0)||($arg1>100))
    {
    $badinput=true;
    }

    if(strlen($arg2)>32)
    {
    $badinput=true;
    }
}

$val=999.99;
$name="asdasdasdasdasdasdasdkjlqjwjejqoipjopoajsopjopqjwpdojqpowdqwdasdasd";

check($val,$name);

if(!$badinput)
    echo "Good";
else 
    echo "Bad input";
?>
```

Is there any problems with the function?

Comment: Please read about php functions and function scope.

Comment: Yes - There are problems - you wrote the call using strings

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

function check($arg1,$arg2)
{
    if(($arg1<0)||($arg1>100) || strlen($arg2)>32)
    {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

$val=999.99;
$name="asdasdasdasdasdasdasdkjlqjwjejqoipjopoajsopjopqjwpdojqpowdqwdasdasd";
if(!check($val,$name))
    echo "Good";
else 
    echo "Bad input";
?>
```

in this case no need to use any variable or variable scopes

now Let me try to explain your problem

in the first line

```
$badinput=false;
```

is outside the function

when you are setting the variable to `true` in the function .the variable scope is restricted to that function only. so it ll not change the `$badinput` value, that is outside the function. so even after the function is called the variable value is still `false`, as it is not affected from the function

so your `$(!badinput)` returns `true` always

Comment: Correct answer (better code than the other ones too). Shame that you didn't include some explanations...

Comment: tried adding some explanation

Answer (score 1):

You are running into scope issues..

Do something like this

```
 $badinput=check($val,$name);
```

No need to make use of **`global`** keyword in this context.

Just rewrite your code like this..

```
<?php
$badinput=false;

function check($arg1,$arg2)
{
    if(($arg1<0)||($arg1>100))
    {
    return true;
    }

    if(strlen($arg2)>32)
    {
    return true;
    }
}

$val=999.99;
$name="asdasdasdasdasdasdasdkjlqjwjejqoipjopoajsopjopqjwpdojqpowdqwdasdasd";

$badinput=check($val,$name); // Now the result of the function will be assigned to $badinput variable

if(!$badinput)
    echo "Good";
else 
    echo "Bad input";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not returning any variables, since the `$badinput` variable is private in the function. Here's how to make it work, you should totally use return statement.

```
function check($arg1,$arg2)
{
 if(($arg1<0)||($arg1>100))
 {
    $badinput=true;
 }

 if(strlen($arg2)>32)
 {
    $badinput=true;
 }
 else {
    $badinput=false;
 }
 return $badinput;
}

$val=999.99;
$name="asdasdasdasdasdasdasdkjlqjwjejqoipjopoajsopjopqjwpdojqpowdqwdasdasd";


if(!check($val,$name))
    echo "Good";
else 
    echo "Bad input";
```

Comment: While your answer is correct, it doesn't attempt to explain what the problem was, exactly what you have changed and why.

Comment: I explained the problem in my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `$badinput` in the `check` function is a local variable. You need to add  `global $badinput;` at the beginning of the function or get the return of this function:

```
function check($arg1,$arg2)
{
    global $badinput;
    if(($arg1<0)||($arg1>100)) {
         $badinput=true;
    }

    if(strlen($arg2)>32) {
        $badinput=true;
    }
}
```

**A better solution is:**

```
function check($arg1,$arg2) {
    $badinput = false;
    if($arg1 < 0 || $arg1 > 100) {
         $badinput=true;
    }

    if(strlen($arg2) > 32) {
         $badinput=true;
    }

    return $badinput;
}


// get result
$badinput = check($val,$name);

if(!$badinput)
    echo "Good";
else 
    echo "Bad input";
```

Comment: While this might technically solve the issue - it is not very good advice to suggest littering your code with the `global` keyword. One should rather address the need to access a specific variable in a certain location and handle that specific case. Your second suggestion is much better.

Comment: Best way is use return statement